# How to wait for a satisfying result from a list of futures?

Tags: java, future, completable-future

In java I have a list of futures that can return a result or null.
How to wait for whichever completes first and if it returns a result then ignore the rest but if it returns null wait for another one to finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a completion handler to each future in your list to complete an auxiliary future:

```
List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = ...
    
var firstNonNull = new CompletableFuture<String>();
futures.forEach(future -> future.whenComplete( (value, failure) -> {
    if (value != null) {
        firstNonNull.complete(value);
    }
}));

firstNonNull.whenComplete(...)
```

Now `firstNonNull` completes once the first future in `futures` completes with a non `null` value.

Comment: Keep in mind that `firstNonNull` will stay forever uncompleted if all incoming futures resulted in `null`.

Comment: i used a little modified version but works in general, thanks !